# Oracle 9 - Case Statement - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle

Let's start with the disclaimers. I have a bunch of SQL experience, but almost no Oracle experience. I'm working off some inherited queries and trying to bend them to my will a bit.

I have written the following query.

```
set colsep ,
set echo off
set feedback off
set heading off
set headsep off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
set tab off
set term off
set trimspool on
set verify off

DEFINE SEP = CHR(31)

SPOOL "&&1"

SELECT (RAG_SKUS_ST.SKU || '_' || RAG_SKUS_ST.STORE
  || &&SEP || RAG_SKUS_ST.UNIT_RETAIL
  || &&SEP || RAG_STYLE.RECOMMEND_RETAIL
  || &&SEP || ITEM_ZONE_PRICE.UNIT_RETAIL
  || &&SEP || RAG_SKUS_ST.STOCK_ON_HAND
  || &&SEP || (CASE WHEN RAG_SKUS_ST.CLEAR_IND = 'N' AND GROUPS.DIVISION = 90 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END) IS_CLEARANCE
  || CHR(10))
FROM
  RAG_SKUS_ST,
  RAG_SKUS,
  RAG_STYLE,
  DEPS,
  GROUPS,
  ITEM_ZONE_PRICE
WHERE
  RAG_SKUS_ST.SKU                 = RAG_SKUS.SKU    AND
  RAG_SKUS.STYLE                  = RAG_STYLE.STYLE AND
  DEPS.DEPT                       = RAG_STYLE.DEPT  AND
  GROUPS.GROUP_NO                 = DEPS.GROUP_NO   AND
  ITEM_ZONE_PRICE.ITEM            = RAG_SKUS.SKU    AND
  ITEM_ZONE_PRICE.BASE_RETAIL_IND = 'Y'             AND
  RAG_SKUS_ST.SKU                 LIKE '%&&3'       AND
  RAG_SKUS_ST.STORE               = &&2;

SPOOL OFF
```

This query throws an error **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis** on the line the the case statement.

From reading here or there Oracle seems to throw that error when it encounters code that can't be nested inside other code.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have an alias (`IS_CLEARANCE`) after the `case`, but the next line adds another concatenation. You can only provide an alias for the entire column.

Comment: Thank you, we all feel dumb!